# Error when use Accessor in Chrome - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies, local-storage

Could you help me with this error that Chrome throws at me:

The ERROR it throws at me is this -> Uncaught TypeError: Accessor properties are not allowed.

```
*jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Accessor properties are not allowed.
at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
at Storage.value (script.js:139)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:91)
at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)*
```

Here is the code of my functions:

```
// Functions
// object.watch
if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
  enumerable: false
, configurable: true
, writable: false
, value: function (prop, handler) {
    var
      oldval = this[prop]
    , newval = oldval
    , getter = function () {
        return newval;
    }
    , setter = function (val) {
        oldval = newval;
        return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
    }
    ;

    if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
        Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
              get: getter
            , set: setter
            , enumerable: true
            , configurable: true
        });
    }
}
});
}

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
  enumerable: false
, configurable: true
, writable: false
, value: function (prop) {
    var val = this[prop];
    delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
    this[prop] = val;
}
});
}
```

In firefox / mozilla it does not throw me this error and without problems I handle these functions and accessors !!! Will someone know why it happens?

Thank you!!!